# vb.net insert checkbox value into database

Tags: vb.net

i am new vb.net beginner. i have some question about vb.net insert checkbox value into database.
I finished the frontend and backend coding and i want to know any easy way to deploy the checkbox value insert into database. thanks!

```html
Frontend
<td>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkbox" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="uamCheckBox" Width="10px" />
</td>
```

```html
BackEnd

Dim ckbox As String = If(checkbox.Checked, "Y", "N")

Using checkbox As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (checkbox) VALUES(@checkbox)")
checkbox.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkbox", ckbox)
End Using
```

Comment: Are you sure the DataType of the checkbox field is a string type? It should be be bit.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you table is not named table. You will substitute the name of your table for the word table in you sql string. Also I assume the name of the column is checkbox.

I would suggest more descriptive names for your controls.

I renamed the command because the code was confusing the control and the command name.

If this really is stored as a String type then

```
Private Sub InsertDatabase()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
        chbox As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (checkbox) VALUES(@checkbox)", cn)
        chbox.Parameters.Add("@checkbox", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = If(checkbox.Checked, "Y", "N")
        cn.Open()
        chbox.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

If it is a bit, as it should be then

```
        chbox.Parameters.Add("@checkbox", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = checkbox.Checked
```